# Operator \> and \< (string version comparison) are not recognised in shell script

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting, cassandra, openindiana, smartos

I am trying to run Casandra nodetool and getting warnings coming from .sh script.

```
[root@d11ca4cc-fa95-c8a9-e133-e64c434f0e6f ~]# nodetool status
/opt/local/share/cassandra/bin/nodetool[53]: .[97]: [: <: unknown operator
/opt/local/share/cassandra/bin/nodetool[53]: .[102]: [: <: unknown operator
prtconf: devinfo facility not available
/opt/local/share/cassandra/bin/nodetool[53]: .[222]: [: <: unknown operator
```

At line 53 nodetool is calling cassandra-env.sh.

In cassandra-env.sh (lines 97, 102, 222):

```
...
97  if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.7" ] ; then
...
if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.8" ] && [ "$JVM_PATCH_VERSION" -lt "25" ] ; then
...
if { [ "$JVM_VERSION" \> "1.7" ] && [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.8.0" ] && [ "$JVM_PATCH_VERSION" -ge "60" ]; } || [ "$JVM_VERSION" \> "1.8" ] ; then
...
```

I am not sure where the problem is but it looks to me like operator `\>` or `\<` is not recognised. Any advise?

Comment: Where does this operator comes from ?

Comment: What is the shebang at the top of the cassandra-env.sh file ?

Comment: There is `!/bin/sh` in root file (nodetool) but nothing in cassandra-env.sh

Comment: It's gone when I changed it to `!/bin/bash`, thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact, bash recognises `\>` and `\<` just fine and compares string versions, for example, "1.7.0" will be recognised as "1.7".

Comment: @ruruskyi Oh ok, that's good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a Solaris system to hand but it appears that the script is relying on /bin/sh being a link to /bin/bash and as such is using bash syntax that sh doesn't understand.

As you've discovered changing the shebang to #!/bin/bash fixes the problem.

You should submit a bug report and hopefully the maintainers will  fix it to be less Linux centric.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already filed this issue to maintainers of the package.